# Can't route to both "{controller}/{action}/{id}" and "{controller}/{id}"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC website, I'd like to have my routes set up like this:

- `site.com/Customer` - where you can select a customer.
- `site.com/Customer/123` - where you can see the information for the selected customer.

So basically, having just one view that depending on if you have an `{id}` shows different stuff.

So I add the mapped route `DefaultNoAction` in `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
// Route definitions.
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultNoAction",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Parameters2",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id1 = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And the following in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

and the view:

```
@model int?

...

$(function () {
    var customerId = @Model;
    ...
}
```

Now:

- If I try accessing `site.com/Customer/123` I'll get a 404.
- If I go to `site.com/Customer` the `@Model` is not set to anything, so when I reference it in my jQuery it throws a syntax error because it'll see `var customerId = ;`

Obviously I'm not approaching this the right way or there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do. Any direction?

Comment: Just a quick check - did you remove the default route for `{controller}/{action}/{id}`?

Comment: Is that route before the default route (the order matters)

Comment: Would it be okay to ask to put the full RouteConfig.cs here? You can definitely go for attribute routing.

Comment: I added my whole `RouteConfig.cs`.

Comment: You need to move the `DefaultNoAction` before the `Default` route - `/Customer/123` matches the default route (it contains 2 segments) and its trying to find the (invalid) `123` method in `CustomerController` (and your `Parameters2` route wont work either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your routes matter (the routing engine will stop searching when it finds the first match). `../Customer/123` matches you `Default` route (it contains 2 segments) and you get a `404` because there is no method named `123` in your `CustomerController`. You need to move the `DefaultNoAction` route before the `Default` route.

However this may cause other issues with your routing and you should make the `DefaultNoAction` route unique if you also want to use the `Default` route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultNoAction",
    url: "Customer/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

As for the javascript error, assuming you want the value of `customerId` to be `null` if the methods `id` parameter is `null`, then you can use

```
var customerId = @Html.Raw(Json..Encode(Model));
console.log(customerId); // returns null if the model is null
```

As a side note, your `Parameters2` route will not work correctly either. Only the last parameter can be marked as `Url.Optional`, and if only one or the 2 parameters were provided it would match the `Default` route.

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute routing for it

```
[Route("api/Customer/{id:int?}")]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    if (id!=null)     
      return View(id);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The 'useful' edit is not useful at all - it's identical to the original `return View(id);` code

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it true but OP,s problem is the route so if he solve it then other logic he can implement

Answer (score 1):

Change order in route config. Second configuration should be first. I don't check but I think that framework interprets url `site.com/Customer/123` like `Customer` is controller and `123` is the name of action.

View should looks like:

```
@model int?

...

$(function () {
    var customerId = @(Model ?? 0);
    ...
}
```